# How to make picture responsive to windows size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In fullscreen everything is okay. Image is on the right and in the middle. If I resize the window of browser the picture is out of place. I want it to be under the text in the middle.

[image: ok]

[image: not ok]

Can you help me somehow?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="welcome" class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
        <h1 class="thinh1">
          Mým cílem
        </h1>
        <h1>
          <strong>je Vaše spokojenost.</strong>
        </h1>
        <p class="welcomep">
          Vytvořím Vám webové stránky pro Vaše účely.
          <br> Vaše stránky, Vaše vizitka.
        </p>

        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/cenik.html">Chci vytvořit webové stránky</a></button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
        <img class="rounded-circle float-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="mme" width="250" height="250" />
      </div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version per the instructions on the twitter-bootstrap tag.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly just need to [text-align](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment) the div around the image. The `text-center` class centers for mobile, and `text-md-end` aligns to the end of the parent on medium screens and up.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="welcome" class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
        <h1 class="thinh1"> Mým cílem </h1>

        <h1> <strong>je Vaše spokojenost.</strong> </h1>

        <p class="welcomep">
          Vytvořím Vám webové stránky pro Vaše účely.
          <br> Vaše stránky, Vaše vizitka.
        </p>

        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/cenik.html">Chci vytvořit webové stránky</a></button>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="mme" width="250" height="250" />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add img-fluid or img-responsive depends on your version of bootstrap. You can also add w-100 h-100 in the class. I will post examples below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="welcome" class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
        <h1 class="thinh1"> Mým cílem </h1>

        <h1> <strong>je Vaše spokojenost.</strong> </h1>

        <p class="welcomep">
          Vytvořím Vám webové stránky pro Vaše účely.
          <br> Vaše stránky, Vaše vizitka.
        </p>

        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/cenik.html">Chci vytvořit webové stránky</a></button>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="mme" width="250" height="250" />
      </div>
```

Second example with w-100 h-100

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="welcome" class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
        <h1 class="thinh1"> Mým cílem </h1>

        <h1> <strong>je Vaše spokojenost.</strong> </h1>

        <p class="welcomep">
          Vytvořím Vám webové stránky pro Vaše účely.
          <br> Vaše stránky, Vaše vizitka.
        </p>

        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/cenik.html">Chci vytvořit webové stránky</a></button>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
        <img class="rounded-circle w-100 h-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="mme" width="250" height="250" />
      </div>
```